# Can't set ViewSize of UWP window on the first app launch

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-core, uwp

I've read a lot of tickets here and in other forums about this issue. None of them managed to help me.

What I need is simple - on first app launch, I need the app started in maximized window (NOT full screen though). In any other case, I want the app to size automatically (which is the last size it was closed with).

In here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.preferredlaunchwindowingmode?view=winrt-18362

..it is said that:
*For the very first launch of an app the PreferredLaunchWindowingMode will always be Auto and the ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize will be determined by system policies. The API applies to the next launch of the app.*

Unfortunately, that seems to happen every time the PreferredLaunchWindowingMode is Auto. That means that I can never switch from Auto to PreferredLaunchViewSize in the scope of my current session.

When PreferredLaunchWindowingMode is Auto, **neither** ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize, nor ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(size) work. They trigger with the correct size, but they change nothing.

What I want is an alternative, that will actually resize my window, without secret dependencies and forced behavior.

My current code:

App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (true/*SystemInformation.IsFirstRun*/)
    {
       var displayInfo = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
       Size displaySize = new Size(displayInfo.ScreenWidthInRawPixels, displayInfo.ScreenHeightInRawPixels);
       ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = displaySize;
       ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
       ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(displaySize);  // This DOESN'T work on first launch
    }
    else
    {
      ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.Auto; // This does not get called, because I don't need it yet. When maximizing works, I will run this row for subsequent startups.
    }
    ...
}
```

MainView.xaml:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        var displayInfo = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
        Size size = new Size(displayInfo.ScreenWidthInRawPixels, displayInfo.ScreenHeightInRawPixels);
        var appView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
        appView.TryResizeView(size);

...
}
```

I've tried changing PreferredLaunchWindowingMode before/after InitializeComponent. I've also tried moving  app.xaml.cs snippet in other places of my OnLaunched method. It never works when Mode is Auto, it always worked when Mode was PreferredLaunchViewSize.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I understand what you want to achieve. Could you please tell me what's the behavior you are getting now? Do you mean when the `PreferredLaunchWindowingMode` is `Auto`, the size of the windows is not the size that you set using PreferredLaunchViewSize?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Correct. Maximized size fails to apply. When mode is PreferredLaunchViewSize, it maximizes correctly. When I change modes, it doesn't apply change immediately, but for the next run. So I can't really apply my logic that way.

Comment: What about setting the `PreferredLaunchWindowingMode` to `Auto` after the  `Window.Current.Activate()` method? When you launch the app for the first time and maximizes the window after Window.Current.Activate(), you could set `PreferredLaunchWindowingMode` to `Auto` so that when you launch the app for the second time, the property is alread applied.

Comment: Well, I never had problem with that. Actually, it was in my code and I deleted it for simplification. My problem is the complete opposite - I need to maximize window in a session that started with PreferredLaunchWindowingMode Auto.

Comment: If you set the `PreferredLaunchWindowingMode` to Auto, the `PreferredLaunchViewSize` will be determined by system policies. This is mentioned in the document and that's why you can't set the size.  If you want to set your app in a maximized window but not full screen using `PreferredLaunchViewSize`, you might still need to change the `PreferredLaunchWindowingMode ` property.

Comment: Man, I know that already. As you can see in my code, I change the PreferredLaunchWindowingMode. It doesn't work. Change does not apply instantly. I want it to apply instantly and allow me to maximize window. It just doesn't happen that way. That's why i'm searching for alternatives.

Comment: Maybe I haven't made myself clear. I mean add it after the ` Window.Current.Activate()` . Set the `PreferredLaunchWindowingMode` to Auto after  ` Window.Current.Activate()` when the app is running for the first time.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Dear Roy. I'm sorry, I know you're trying to help, but you don't understand what I am asking. PreferredLaunchWindowingMode  is Auto by default, so I don't need to set it to Auto. I want to set it to PreferredLaunchViewSize. I want that change to take effect and allow me to resize. I don't care about Auto. I can delete that row for all I care. It isn't fired anyway. My main goal is to resize the window according to dimensions I want. I can't do that. Not in the first launch. You're taking the discussion the wrong way. I'm sorry if I sound aggressive.

Comment: Based on the previous comment, in the first launch, the app needs to be maxed, and then for all the launch after, the app needs to launch at the size which is closed before, right?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Yes, that's correct. And in the first launch the setting is Auto by default, which stops me from achieving my goal.